# How to display a Boolean value as a check box in a table?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I have a value in Salesforce that comes back from the database as either True or False. Based on what the value is, I was to display a check box in a column of a table. Here is what I tried:

```
<apex:column headerValue="checkbox">
  <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!myObj.isChecked}" disabled="true" id="checkbox" />
</apex:column>
```

However this always just returns a checkbox that is always unchecked no matter what *myObj.isChecked* is. 
Thanks!

Comment: Try just putting {!myObj.isChecked} outside the checkbox input to confirm its value isn't always false

Comment: I recommend the following resources [Visualforce Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_vf.meta/workbook_vf/workbook_vf_intro.htm) and the [Visualforce Developer’s Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm).

Comment: Thanks @PhilB it looked like there was an error elsewhere and I'm always getting back false. Good call, thank you!

Comment: Great! No problem I put it in an answer as well for anyone with this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just putting `{!myObj.isChecked}` outside the checkbox input to confirm its value isn't always false. It sounds like it might actually always be false.